# Como validar un textBox para que solo se ingresen números en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quisiera saber como implementar una validación en un textBox, solo para que acepte 13 números ingresados por el usuario.
Que aparezca un mensaje indicando que "solo se permite un máximo de 13 números"

Implemento esta instrucción en mi textBox:

> `string.IsNullOrEmpty();`

Estoy usando Window Form.

Comment: ok, eso es para saber si no ingreso nada. y el resto? 13 numeros o menos? solo numeros? que probaste ademas de eso?

Comment: web o desktop??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int i;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        //vacío
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length < 5)
        {
            //inferior a cinco caracteres
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out i))
            {
                //no numérico
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

    if (e.Cancel)
        MessageBox.Show("El campo debe contener un valor numérico de 5 dígitos");
}

private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                                                  
    //todo ok, se cancela el error                 
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "");         
}
```

Comment: Y si el usuario está usando Windows Forms o WPF... ¿Cómo usa el código en tu respuesta?

Comment: y esto que tiene que ver con lo que pregunta? Fijate que en ningun momento dijo que era HTML. es mas, sigue sin aclarar que patron necesita. Por favor antes de contestar esperar a que la pregunta este bien formulada y sea correcta.

Comment: Comprendo tu problema, disculpas crei que el escenario era web. Puedes solucionarlo usando !IsNumeric(textBox1.Text)

Comment: edita tu respuesta bro :D

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar los eventos Validating y Validate junto con ErrorProvider, algo así (ojo, el ejemplo requiere que el campo tenga cinco caracteres, debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades y lo ideal sería preguntar primero si es numérico):

```
<!-- language: c# -->
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    int i;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        //vacío
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length < 5)
        {
            //inferior a cinco caracteres
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
            if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out i))
            {
                //no numérico
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

    if (e.Cancel)
        MessageBox.Show("El campo debe contener un valor numérico de 5 dígitos");
}

private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                                                  
    //todo ok, se cancela el error                 
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "");         
}
```

Comment: Si alguien sabe porque sale el código a medio colorear que me lo diga